# Regular expression in Java: Converting URLs

Tags: java, regex, url, hyperlink

I have a question according regular expressions in Java. I have following code to convert URLs in the related HTML-Hyperlinks:

```
String groupEndOfURL = "[^ \"\\|\\t\\n\\r<]";
dummy = dummy.replaceAll("([\\w]+?://"+groupEndOfURL+"*)","<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

This does convert following URL correctly:
`http://www.vsa-verlag.de/index.php?id=6576&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=15147`

However, following reference from a BibTex entry:

Engelhardt A, Kajetzke L (2010): Handbuch Wissensgesellschaft. Theorien, Themen und Probleme. Bielefeld: transcript [http://www.transcript-verlag.de/978-3-8376-1324-7/handbuch-wissensgesellschaft]

includes the trailing `]` in the hyperlink, which should not happen (same bug seems to be here at stack overflow, see above).

Doing following (adding `\\[` and `\\]`):

```
String groupEndOfURL = "[^ \"\\|\\[\\]\\t\\n\\r<]";
dummy = dummy.replaceAll("([\\w]+?://"+groupEndOfURL+"*)","<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```

does not correctly convert the first URL-example, because the hyperlink stops at `[tt_news]=15147`.

So, does anybody know how I do have to modify my regular expression to accept `[` and `]` inside URLs, but not when they are just "enquoting" a link?

Using `([\w]+?://[^ "\|\t\n\r<]*)(?=\])?` does not exactly fit, it includes the `]` in the lower example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just tried your regex with atom and it works correctly matching only the url :

[image: example]

To let it work with both URLs just change your regex like this :

```
\[([\w]+?://[^ "\|\t\n\r<]*)\]
```

if the regex engine supports the lookbehind and lookforward, you can even avoid the two enclosing square brackets to be part of the matching expression :

```
(?<=\[)([\w]+?://[^ "\|\t\n\r<]*)(?=\])
```

**Updated regex after comments** :

```
([\w]+?://[^ "\|\t\n\r<]*)(?=\])?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it does not meet both conditions. Both your suggestions don't recognize the first URL example `http://www.vsa-verlag.de/index.php?id=6576&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=15147`. Your first suggestion converts `[http://www.transcript-verlag.de/978-3-8376-1324-7/handbuch-wissensgesellschaft]`, but removes the parentheses `[` and `]` and your second suggestion with lookahead/-behind works fine for the second URL example.

Comment: @Daniel take look at the updated post and look at the image, you can see that that the last expression works correctly with both of your examples .

Comment: If the first URL is surrounded by `[` and `]`, it does match. However, the first URL is considered to be in a text paragraph or as single line, not belonging to a reference (and thus not being surrounded by `[` and `]`). In this case, only one match is found. That's the difficult part of my matching problem. ;-)

Comment: @Daniel then you can just put optional final lookahead, take a look at the updated post .

Comment: sorry for coming back to this thread so late. I tested your latest suggestion, however, for me it does not exactly work (see my edited post above, including screenshot from atom). I'll "give up" this issue and decided to consider `[` and `]` not being part of hyperlinks. There are not many situations where you have such cases, I guess.